# Dead link in documentation

Tags: bug, status-completed, documentation

On the [docs for question timelines](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/types/question-timeline) the link for "Question" points to `/docs/type/question` when it should point to `/docs/types/question`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This, and a few other documentation typos and errors, was fixed in the latest deploy.